# ionic 2 ion-select click(ionChange) Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: angular, ionic2

HTML

```
{{selectedCategory}}
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedCategory" (ionChange)="updateproduct()">
```

js

```
updateproduct(){
consolo.log(this.selectedCategory);
}
```

When I select category 
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

this error is shown but if I close the error, `selectedCategory` seems. whats wrong I don't understand.

Comment: are you calling `length` anywhere else?

Comment: also in your code, it needs to be `console.log`.

Comment: yes its console.log.
thanks for helping. i fixed.

updateproduct() for calling in a different place.
it was not supposed to be. but it is

Answer (score 0):

i fixed. updateproduct() for calling in a different place. it was not supposed to be. but it is

Comment: can you explain the context? might help others with the problem?